# VertexContract, VertexReplace and non-anonymous collapsed node

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Can the standard `VertexContract` or `VertexReplace` functions display a name for the collapsed node ?

Here is a minimal example:

```
`adg = Graph[{"U" \[DirectedEdge] "D", "D" \[DirectedEdge] "T", 
   "T" \[DirectedEdge] "Q"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`
VertexList @ %
{"U", "D", "T", "Q"}
```

`VertexContract` displays an anonymous node, even though the name is the list:

```
    adgagg2 = 
     VertexReplace[SimpleGraph @ VertexContract[adg, {"D", "T"}], "D" -> "B"]
    VertexList[adgagg2]
(*{"U", "B", "Q"}*)
```

`VertexReplace` removes the labels in the display:

```
 adgagg = SimpleGraph@VertexReplace[adg, {"D" -> "B", "T" -> "B"}]
    VertexList[adgagg]
(*{"U", "B", "Q"}*)
```

Just wondering if I am missing a simple option somewhere. Clearly this can be addressed programmatically.

Best

Trad.

Comment: `adgagg = SimpleGraph[VertexReplace[adg, {"D" -> "B", "T" -> "B"}], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]` ?

Comment: or `SetProperty[VertexReplace[adg, "D" -> "B"], VertexLabels -> "Name"]`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. Trad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use for example

```
SetProperty[VertexReplace[adg, "D" -> "B"], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```